# Not receiving the complete JSON

Tags: android, json, url, request, fragment

At the stage of obtaining JSON, part of all data comes, and in the log error:

Can't convert to JSONArray

I looked at similar questions and did not find the answer I needed, thanks

```
URL = "http://legs-legs.ru/cat1json.php?json=cat1";
...
HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);
            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);
            if (url != null) {
                try {
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(url);
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = null;
                        c = array.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString("id");
```

Request here:

Log.e(TAG,response) gives me uncomleted string

```
    public class HttpHandler {

    private static final String TAG = HttpHandler.class.getSimpleName();

    public HttpHandler() {
    }

    public String makeServiceCall(String reqUrl) {
        String response = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) 
            url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            // read the response
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            response = convertStreamToString(in);
        } catch ...
        return response;
    }

    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append('\n');
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Log.e(TAG,sb.toString());
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can't convert to JSONArray

Because there is mistake   your JSON respose String is **`jsonStr`** not **`url`** change it

Use this

```
 URL = "http://legs-legs.ru/cat1json.php?json=cat1";
 String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);
            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);
            if (url != null) {
                try {
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                    // json parsing code
```

Instead of this

```
 URL = "http://legs-legs.ru/cat1json.php?json=cat1";
 String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);
            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);
            if (url != null) {
                try {
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(url);
```

Comment: may i know the reason for down vote

Answer (score 0):

Change this line to-:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(url);
```

To-:

```
String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this 
`JSONArray array = new JSONArray(url);`
with: 
`JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonStr);`

pass `jsonStr` in `JSONArray()` constructor instead of `url`